# In python postgres sql , create and insert query is executing without error but while checking in the database it is not getting updated

Tags: python, postgresql

In python postgres sql , create and insert query is executing without error but while checking in the database it is not getting updated

**Python code**

```
cursor = self.connection.cursor()

try:

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO success(username,email)VALUES('test5','test@mail')")

        print ("A row Inserted successfully")

except Exception as e:

       print ("Unable to insert your data - ",e)
```

**Output**

```
A row Inserted successfully
```

But the data not truly inserted into database. The select query is working fine and displaying the data which is already available in the database not newly inserted.

**select Query below**

```
cursor.execute("select * from success")

record = cursor.fetchall()

print ("record",record)
```

**output**

```
record []
```

**Note:** All the database connections are working fine I have checked it already. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any trigger on the table?

Comment: Try `self.connection.commit()` after `cursor.execute(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked out - @awesoon